# iptables: How to block UDP between devices on LAN-side of gateway (using dd-wrt firmware)

Tags: iptables, router, gateway, block

**Goal**: To block UDP traffic to devices on LAN-side of this gateway (using dd-wrt firmware), that communicate with internet and each other, to test specific communications applications running on each device.

**Exceptions**: allow the bare minimum UDP needed to support basic network operations for these devices to continue communicating (eg: via TCP) with internet and each other.

**What I've tried so far**:
Added rules (via SSH session) on this router/gateway:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p udp -j DROP 
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -j DROP
```

**Observed (what's working well)**:

- The rule `iptables -I FORWARD -p udp -j DROP` successfully blocks devices on LAN-side from communicating via UDP with devices on WAN-side, as verified by inability to communicate between these devices with utility `ncat -u`.

**Observed (what's not working)**:

- Devices on LAN-side can communicate with each other, using UDP:

  - On device-1 (on LAN-side): `ncat -lvu`  # launch ncat listener using UDP on default port 31337
  - On device-2 (on LAN-side): `ncat -vu <ip-addr-device-1>` # launch ncat caller using UDP on default port 31337

**Expectation (desired outcome)**:

- ncat caller on device-2 **unable** to communicate using UDP to ncat listener on device-1.
- ncat caller on device-2 **able** to communicate using TCP to ncat listener on device-1, by not using ncat param `-u`.

**Additional info**:

- Using command `iptables -I INPUT -p udp -j DROP` impacts too much other communication, but used anyways, to demonstrate ineffectiveness of this rule in preventing UDP communicaiton between these two devices.
- Using hardware: tp-link AC1750 (Archer C7 v5)
- Using firmware: dd-wrt, with setting "Operating Mode = Gateway"
- Devices behind gateway are UWP, iOS, Android.  Examples given here using UWP (Windows 10) devices.
- I've seen [How do I block UDP while still allowing outbound UDP connections with iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/817377/how-do-i-block-udp-while-still-allowing-outbound-udp-connections-with-iptables), but doesn't appear effective in my case, as demonstrated by trying `iptables -I INPUT -p udp -j DROP`.

Comment: Check [ebtables](https://web.archive.org/web/20210902064033/https://ebtables.netfilter.org/) and if you insist on using the wrong tool, here's some rope to hang oneself: [br_netfilter](https://web.archive.org/web/20210529184120/http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) except it's [disabled](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/firewall_components#kernel_tuning_via_sysctl) in OpenWRT so might be in DD-WRT too.

Comment: Bridged traffic (same layer-2 domain) does not pass through a routers, so you cannot use a router to block the traffic. A switch or WAP is a layer-2 bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you cannot interfere with the LAN-to-LAN traffic. All devices that I know that run DD-WRT / OpenWRT have an integrated switch, that switches traffic directly between LAN devices on layer 2.

Only traffic that needs forwarding is passed to the router part (layer 3) of the system, where Netfilter can intercept the traffic.

You can try setting up a Linux box with multiple Ethernet adapters and then bridging those adapters together. Then you can use `br_netfilter` to force the L2 traffic go via Netfilter, allowing intercepting of the traffic.

Comment: This answer appears corroborated by comment from @ron-maupin, and both sound reasonable to me. 
To solve my problem: I'll put other devices behind different routers, which means rules in `FORWARD` table should be effective in blocking UDP between these devices.. Thanks!